# preventDefault doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, preventdefault

I have a problem with preventDefault function. It doesn't work. Here is my JS file:

```
(function() {
    var app = {
        initialize : function () {
            this.setUpListeners();
        },
        setUpListeners: function () {
            $('form').on('submit', app.submitForm);
        },
        submitForm: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();                
        }
    }

    app.initialize(); 
}());
```

My HTML code has 2 confirm button. Second step is hidden and should be display, when first step will be done. But I can't at least add preventDefault for first step.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form id="login">
    <!-- #first_step -->
    <div id="first_step">

        <h1>Registration Form</h1>
        <fieldset id="inputs">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Create a username" required="">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Create a password" required="">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cpassword">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="cpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm your password">
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="actions">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit_first" id="submit_first" value="Next">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <!-- #second_step -->
    <div id="second_step">
        <h1>Registration Form</h1>
        <fieldset id="inputs">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name" autofocus="" required="">

            <label>Surname</label>
            <input type="text" name="surname" id="lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your last name" required="">

            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email" required="">
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="actions">
            <input  class="submit" type="submit" name="submit_second" id="submit_second" value="Next">
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm sorry. I'm just a beginner in js and will be very thankful if someone help me

Comment: 99% sure you forgot `$` before your `(function()...`)

Comment: @Amit it is anonymous function

Comment: @Amit Why should there be a `$`? It's a self invoking anonymous function, the syntax is fine. **@OP**: Are you getting any JS errors?

Comment: Did you forget to load jquery?  You are using it here: `$('form').on('submit', app.submitForm);`

Comment: @Quasdunk, Alexander - Because it looks like the classic jQuery syntax for running the code when the page is ready, where otherwise if the form element doesn't exist yet everything will fail

Comment: No, jquery loaded properly.

Comment: http://graf.co.nf/register.php - here is a link in Internet

Comment: This JS work fine - http://graf.co.nf/js/jquery.main.js but I want to realize this page using functions like here http://graf.co.nf/js/test.js

Comment: As I said, you forgot the `$`

Comment: It doesn't work also with $

Comment: Here is an example, where this function work without $ -- http://graf.co.nf/View/test.html

Comment: @SergeyPodgornyy It works there because the script is at the end, so the elements have been loaded. If you run the script at the beginning, none of the elements it tries to select exist yet.

Comment: That seems to be the difference between your two links. The working one loads `common.js` at the end, the failing one loads it at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    var app = {
        initialize : function () {
            this.setUpListeners();
        },
        setUpListeners: function () {
            $('form').on('submit', app.submitForm);
        },
        submitForm: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();                
        }
    }

    app.initialize(); 
});
```