# javascript preventDefault doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my new order view I have:

```
<a id="showhidetrigger1" class='btn btn-primary' 
            onclick="clicked('showhidetarget1');"><%= current_user.titles[0] %></a>

<a id="showhidetrigger2" class='btn btn-primary'
            onclick="clicked('showhidetarget2');"><%= current_user.titles[2] %></a>

<a id="showhidetrigger3" class='btn btn-primary'
            onclick="clicked('showhidetarget3');"><%= current_user.titles[1] %></a>

<div id="showhidetarget1" class='center'>
    <p><%= render :partial => "productstype", 
                  :locals => {:selectedproduct => @current.bottles, :title => @current.titles[0] } %>
    </p> 
</div>

<div id="showhidetarget2" class='center'>
    <p><%= render :partial => "productstype", 
                  :locals => {:selectedproduct => @current.pourings, :title => @current.titles[2] } %>
    </p>
</div>

<div id="showhidetarget3" class='center'>
    <p><%= render :partial => "productstype", 
                  :locals => {:selectedproduct => @current.cocktails, :title => @current.titles[1] } %>
    </p>
</div>
```

and in order.js I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    hideall = function() {
        $('#showhidetarget1').hide();
        $('#showhidetarget2').hide();
        $('#showhidetarget3').hide();
    };

    hideall();

    window.clicked = function(item) {

        hideall();
        event = event || window.event;
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('#' + item).toggle(400);
        return false;
    };    

});
```

Hide/show works fine but I can't avoid scrolling on top when buttons are clicked.
I already tried several solution ([like these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171076/preventdefault-doesnt-work) and others on stack) but none worked.

Edit: solved using jquery as suggested... [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967081/show-hide-multiple-divs-with-jquery) Thanks to everyone!!!
So my jquery function is:

```
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
        jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
              jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
              jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
        });
});
```

Comment: Have you got any errors in the console?

Comment: i'm not sure but i think the event parameter should be passed in the function!!

Comment: No errrors in console...

Comment: `window.clicked` there is no `clicked` event, use `onclick` or `addEventListener` or even better use jquery, which will attach event crossbrowserly. `$(document).click(function(){...})`

Answer (score 3):

You need something more like this:

```
$(window).on('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  // Do whatever logic here
});
```

If you're using plain Javascript, then you will need something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  // Do something else
});
```

Comment: ya, this is what i'm talking about! :)

Comment: This is correct for someone using jQuery, but not otherwise.

Comment: Plain JS solution for @Pointy

Comment: @druido82, your callback will not be passed anything except the jquery Event and maybe some custom data, if you trigger it yourself, which you're not according to your code. Where is `item` coming from?

Comment: @arjabbar I apologize for not noticing that the OP is apparently using jQuery! However it's nice that you added the alternative.

Comment: I try to be accommodating to everyone. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to everyone for interest, @arjabbar item came from `  onclick="clicked('showhidetarget1');  ` in the view...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, then write all code in jQuery.
This is modified code which should work.

jQuery returns event object as a first argument, so I changed item to event. You can access to current element with this context, like this `$(this)`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var hideall = function() {
        $('#showhidetarget1').hide();
        $('#showhidetarget2').hide();
        $('#showhidetarget3').hide();
    };

    hideall();

    $(document).click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        hideall();
        $(this).toggle(400);
    });    

});
```

Comment: Tried this but I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: clicked is not defined" errror...

Comment: right cuz there is no clicked method or variable, where you see `clicked` in my code?

Answer (score -1):

You have to move the **preventDefault** code to item click instead of window.
The reason why is quite simple: window is the last element of the event chain, so nothing else to prevent the bubble ;)